# What are createReceive and createReceiveRecover methods for in AbstractPersistenceActor?

Tags: java, version, akka-persistence

I was going through a TypeSafe downloaded AkkaJava.pdf file detailing based on 2.3.2 API. In chapter 4.4 Persistence (Java with Lambda Support), it lists the `receiveRecover()` and `receiveCommand()` are the methods that need to be overridden to process messages.

Now I have set my IDE to use 2.5.2 version of AKKA and it has the `createReceive()` and `createReceiveRecover()` as the methods that need to be overridden from the abstract class I extend from.

What are these methods for? The names do not seem intuitive for me. Am I looking at wrong methods for processing messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it has been explained in [Akka Docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html)

They replace the old methods that are up to 2.4 version.